# Evento onBlur en TabView de Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

Buenas noches.
Necesito capturar el evento onblur entre pestañas (tabviews) antes que el enfoque cambie a la nueva pestaña.

La plantilla pintara los nuevos tab cada vez que seleccione un nuevo cliente

**plantilla.xhmlt**

```
    <ui:composition template="./../template/plantilla.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <p:tabView id="tabViewMain"                            
                       dynamic="true" 
                       cache="false" 
                       activeIndex="#{tabController.curTabIndex}">     

                <p:ajax event="tabClose" 
                        listener="#{tabController.onTabClose}"/>
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" 
                        listener="#{tabController.onTabChange}"/>
                <c:forEach items="#{tabController.listaIfacesTabs}" 
                           var="tab">
                    <p:tab id="#{tab.idTab}" 
                           title="#{tab.titulo}" 
                           closable="true">                            
                        <ui:include src="#{tab.ruta}"/>                          
                    </p:tab>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:tabView>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

En el bean "TabController" el evento OnChange obtendra el ID del tab actual que a su vez invoca un controlador que cargara la informacion en una nueva vista estadar para clientes

**TabController.java**

```
     @Named
     @SessionScoped
     public class TabController implements Serializable {
        public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        TabView tv = (TabView) event.getTab().getParent();
        this.curTabIndex = tv.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab());
        String idTab = tv.getChildren().get(this.curTabIndex).getId();
        this.loadTabIfacesClienteById(idTab);
        }
    }
```

Si os fijan loadTabIfacesClienteById(idTab) cargara la informacion en una vista cliente **ClienteController**

```
   @Named
   @RequestScoped
   public class ClienteController implements Serializable {

   public void load(IfacesTab facesTab, List<IfacesCliente> listaIfacesClientes) {
    String idTab = facesTab.getIdTab();
    for (IfacesCliente c : listaIfacesClientes) {
        if (c.getIdTab().equals(idTab)) {
            this.cliente = c.getCliente();
            this.listaContactos = c.getListaContactos();
        }
      }
    }

   }
```

**cliente.xhmtl**

```
   <h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{tabController.listaClientes}" 
                 var="cliente"
                 widgetVar="dlgWidBuscarTodoCliente"
                 emptyMessage="No se encontro registros con el criterio"
                 paginator="true" 
                 rows="15" 
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} 
                 {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" 
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="15,60,100">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel style="text-align: right;">
                <h:outputText value="Buscar todos los campos:" />
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" 
                             onkeyup="PF('dlgWidBuscarTodoCliente').filter()" 
                             style="width:150px;" 
                             placeholder="Escriba un criterio"/>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>

        <p:column id="colClienteId" 
                  headerText="Id"
                  visible="true">     
            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.id}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteNombresCompletos" 
                  headerText="Nombres Completos" 
                  sortBy="#{cliente.nombresCompletos}" 
                  filterBy="#{cliente.nombresCompletos}" 
                  filterMatchMode="contains">     
            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.nombresCompletos}"
                          class="textBoxWidth100"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteTipoIdentificacion" 
                  headerText="Tipo de Ident." 
                  sortBy="#{cliente.tipoIdentificacion}" 
                  filterBy="#{cliente.tipoIdentificacion}" 
                  filterMatchMode="in">    
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Tipo de Ident." 
                                      onchange="PF('dlgWidBuscarTodoCliente').filter()" 
                                      panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{globalController.comboClienteTiposIdent}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{globalController.getEtiquetaClienteTiposIdent(cliente.tipoIdentificacion)}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteIdentificacion" 
                  headerText="Identificacion" 
                  sortBy="#{cliente.identificacion}" 
                  filterBy="#{cliente.identificacion}" 
                  filterMatchMode="contains">     
            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.identificacion}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteTipoCliente" 
                  headerText="Tipo de Cliente" 
                  sortBy="#{cliente.tipoCliente}" 
                  filterBy="#{cliente.tipoCliente}" 
                  filterMatchMode="in">     
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Tipo de Cliente" 
                                      onchange="PF('dlgWidBuscarTodoCliente').filter()" 
                                      panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{globalController.comboClienteTipos}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{globalController.getEtiquetaClienteTipos(cliente.tipoCliente)}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteEstadoCivil" 
                  headerText="Estado Civil" 
                  sortBy="#{cliente.estadoCivil}" 
                  filterBy="#{cliente.estadoCivil}" 
                  filterMatchMode="in">   
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Estado Civil" 
                                      onchange="PF('dlgWidBuscarTodoCliente').filter()" 
                                      panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{globalController.comboClienteEstadosCivil}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{globalController.getEtiquetaClienteEstadosCivil(cliente.estadoCivil)}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteGenero" 
                  headerText="Genero" 
                  sortBy="#{cliente.genero}" 
                  filterBy="#{cliente.genero}" 
                  filterMatchMode="in">     
            <f:facet name="filter">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Genero" 
                                      onchange="PF('dlgWidBuscarTodoCliente').filter()" 
                                      panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{globalController.comboClienteGeneros}" />
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{globalController.getEtiquetaClienteGeneros(cliente.genero)}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteFecNacimiento" 
                  headerText="Fec. Nacimiento" 
                  sortBy="#{cliente.fechaNacimiento}" 
                  filterBy="#{cliente.fechaNacimiento}" 
                  filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.fechaNacimiento}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteFecCreacion" 
                  headerText="Fec. Creacion" 
                  sortBy="#{cliente.fechaCreacion}" 
                  filterBy="#{cliente.fechaCreacion}" 
                  filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.fechaCreacion}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="colClienteEditar">
            <p:commandButton 
                id="btnClienteEditar"
                value="Editar" 
                icon="ui-icon-carat-1-e"
                ajax="false"
                action="#{tabController.addTab(
                          '115', 
                          cliente.id,
                          cliente.nombresCompletos, 
                          'pages/cliente_workarea.xhtml'
                          )}" 
                >
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Lo que necesito es cuando la informacion esta cargada en cada vista, si yo deseo cambiarme a otra pestaña, los cambios realizados en la pestaña actual se almacenen en arreglos del TabController principal, dicho de mejora manera antes que pinte la nueva pestaña seleccionada me permita actualizar informacion de los arreglos cosa que si vuelvo a la misma pestaña la informacion estara disponible.

Mas o menos que evitar salir de la pestaña si existen errores de validacion, pero en este caso si cambio de pestaña actualizarla en un evento onblur o lostfoucus

Agradezco su atencion, me indican si me hice entender

Saludos

Comment: Fernando, deberías incluir que has intentado hasta el momento y que has investigado. El atributo onTabChange de <p:tabView> permite realizar una llamada ajax o invocar una función js.